# have csv output as string, have to parse as array in php

Tags: php, csv

I have fetched a csv report which I now have in an string.

```
eg ->
$report="date,pageview,clicks
2012-07-01,229316,16739
2012-07-02,295238,19582
2012-07-03,278505,17805
2012-07-04,209455,15146
2012-07-05,250756,17206";
```

Now I want to save this data in mysql database, but not getting any optimized solution because my real `$report` is very large in size.

Comment: How did you fetch the string? What you should ideally do is convert it to an array as you load it with [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Answer (score 6):

Forget using PHP to import CSV file then sending the data to MySQL- for an optimised solution use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) and load the data straight in, you could use a temporary table if the data isn't exactly what you need

Example :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '<yourcsv>' INTO TABLE <yourtable>
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

**Caveat** - the input file needs to be locally available on the MySQL server

Comment: ...assuming that you have access to the local file system of the MySQL server, which is not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fgetcsv` which read records one by one in an array format.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php